# Errors in core.obj file while linking libusb in Qt 5.0.1

Tags: c++, qt, linker, libusb

I'm trying to link libusb in Qt 5.0.1 on windows 7

```
Here is my .pro file
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = USB01
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

win32: LIBS += -LC:/libusb-1.0.18/Win32/Debug/lib/ -llibusb-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += C:/libusb-1.0.18/libusb
DEPENDPATH += C:/libusb-1.0.18/libusb

win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -shared
```

here is my main.cpp file

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <libusb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    libusb_context *ctx;

    libusb_init (&ctx);
    
    return a.exec();
}
```

Now when I try to build this simple project, I get a dozen or so errors in a core.obj file

> \libusb-1.0.18\Win32\Debug\lib\libusb-1.0\core.obj):-1: error:
> undefined reference to `@__security_check_cookie@4'
>
> \libusb-1.0.18\Win32\Debug\lib\libusb-1.0\core.obj):-1: error:
> undefined reference to `__report_rangecheckfailure'

I have googled these errors and from what I can understand, these errors relate to MSVC++.
I have been able to compile and run multiple simple examples on Qt before this.
Any help on how to resolve these errors?

PS I built libusb on VS 2013 (Express) and I currently have VS 2013 installed on my system as well.

Comment: `-llibusb-1.0` should be `-lusb-1.0`

Comment: Possibly mismatched compile/link flags between your libusb build and your application build (e.g. different security features enabled, or different C runtime libraries).

Comment: @AndrewMedico any possible suggestions for resolving this error?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I did try your suggestion. It always returned the error. Could not find -lusb-1.0

Comment: can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @LaszloPapp this is the first time I have heard this term so I'm gonna ask this... How can I provide a compilable example if my code is not linking/compiling in the first place? Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure I follow, but if people cannot reproduce your issue, they cannot help. You would need to provide a self-contained example reproducing the issue.